# SQL Query Counting Relations Between Two Tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables with user IDs, and another table representing a relation between two users by storing two user IDs. How can I count the mutual relations between two users, with a mutual relation defined as the number of users that two users both have a relation with.

For example if I have:

```
3 - 4
1 - 4
3 - 6
5 - 6
2 - 6
1 - 6
```

I would want my query to return (in order)

```
User1    User2  MutualCount
  1    |    3   |    2
  2    |    3   |    1
  1    |    2   |    1
  1    |    5   |    1
  2    |    5   |    1
  4    |    6   |    1
  3    |    5   |    1
```

And so on...

I'm thinking some sort of Inner Joining of User1/User2, but I can't figure out how the ON part would work, nor how to store and return the count.

I'd appreciate any help!

I've used this to extract all the mutual relations for any two users, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to do it for all users

```
SELECT b.userid,
FROM user b, user c, relation f
WHERE c.user_id = <user id here>
AND (c.user_id = f.user1_id OR c.user_id = f.user2_id)
AND (b.user_id = f.user1_id OR b.user_id = f.user2_id)
INTERSECT
SELECT b.user_id
FROM user b, user c, relation f
WHERE c.user_id = <user id here>
AND (c.user_id = f.user1_id OR c.user_id = f.user2_id)
AND (b.user_id = f.user1_id OR b.user_id = f.user2_id);
```

Comment: Then what you have tried so far ?

Comment: please define **mutual count**.

Comment: Mutual count is the number of relations with a common user between user 1 and user2.

Comment: Where do the `1,6,1` and `3,4,1` results come from? It's not evident from the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** *I threw this out as a first attempt on my way out the door even though it should have been immediately obvious that it couldn't work. (For instance none of the values in columns 1 and 2 are completely disjoint and could never even match.)*

Maybe this?:

```
select
    case when mr1.user1 < mr2.user2 then mr1.user1 else mr2.user2 end as User1,
    case when mr1.user1 < mr2.user2 then mr2.user2 else mr1.user1 end as User2,
    count(*) as MutualCount
from
    mr mr1 inner join mr mr2 on mr1.user2 = mr2.user1
group by
    mr1.user1, mr2.user2
order by
    case when mr1.user1 < mr2.user2 then mr1.user1 else mr2.user2 end,
    case when mr1.user1 < mr2.user2 then mr2.user2 else mr1.user1 end
```

@Joel the problem is a little trickier than it first seemed. The common user could be in either of the two columns and neither of us handled that. That's where the `case` expression come in. I believe a correct solution is below:

```
select
    mr1.user1,
    case when mr1.user2 <> mr2.user1 then mr2.user1 else mr2.user2 end as user2,
    count(*) as MutualCount
from
    mr mr1 inner join mr mr2
        on      mr1.user2 in (mr2.user1, mr2.user2) /* match either user... */
            and mr1.user1 <> mr2.user1 /* ...but not when it's the same row */
where
    mr1.user1 < case when mr1.user2 <> mr2.user1 then mr2.user1 else mr2.user2 end
group by
    mr1.user1,
    case when mr1.user2 <> mr2.user1 then mr2.user1 else mr2.user2 end
order by
    mr1.user1,
    case when mr1.user2 <> mr2.user1 then mr2.user1 else mr2.user2 end
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e652/15

You can also use this same join to find the common users. Just strip out the `group by` and the `count()`.

Comment: I think this only nets a subset of them, but it's close.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user1Id, user2ID, COUNT(*) MutualCount
FROM UserVsUser
GROUP BY user1Id, user2ID
ORDER BY MutualCount DESC
```

UserVsUser is the table representing a relation between two users.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you most of the way there:

```
SELECT r1.user1_id As User1, r2.user1_id As User2, count(*) As MutualCount
FROM relation r1 
INNER JOIN relation r2 ON r1.user2_id = r2.user2_id AND r1.user1_id < r2.user1_id
GROUP BY r1.user1_Id, r2.user1_id
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

This should produce similar results to the current accepted answer, but with less code and faster execution.

> [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef08a/2)

I understand from the sample data why the pair `(1,3)` has a count of `2`, as well as why the pairs `(2,3)`, `(1,2)`, and `(1,5)` all produce a `1`. However,  I don't understand from the sample why `(1,4)`, `(1,6)`, or `(3,4)` show in the results at all, especially when `(2,6)`, `(3,6)` and `(5,6)` are *not* in the sample results. If you can explain that, I have some ideas that may be able to fill in the missing pieces.